# How to pass an array with fixed length strings to a function

Tags: vb6

I am trying to pass an array of fixed length strings to a function. However, the function will not know the size of the strings. The parameter should take any size strings. How would I go about this? Here is my code:

```
Public Type myRecord
    names(15)  As String * 250
End Type
```

Function def:

```
Function HasQuotes(textArr() As String) As String

End Function
```

Usage:

```
HasQuotes(rowRec.names)
```

where `rowRec` is a `MyRecord`.

When I run this code I get the following error `Type Mismatch: array or user defined type expected`. This is because the parameter is not defined as `textArr() As String * 250`. How can I make the parameter accept any string length?

Comment: If "The parameter should take any size strings" then you're dealing with variable-length strings, not fixed-length strings. And in fact your function example does specify variable-length strings.

Comment: How is rowrec.names defined? Is it an array of string * 250 ?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Yes, that is correct. It is an array of string * 250

Comment: Why does `HasQuotes` have to take accept strings of any length?

Comment: Why not pass the UDT instead?

Comment: @BrianMStafford's suggestion seems the most plausible one. And pass the size of the fixed-length as a second parameter, e.g. `Function HasQuotes(ByRef udt As myRecord, ByVal lStringLen As Long) As String`

Answer (score 0):

You Have to follow Proper syntax you can Try Following updated Code

```
Private Type myRecord
    names(15) As String * 250
End Type

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim rowRec As myRecord
    rowRec.names(0) = ("Vaibhav")

    Dim v As String
    v = HasQuotes(rowRec.names)

End Sub

Function HasQuotes(ByRef textArr() As String * 250) As String
    MsgBox textArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: The OP says that the `HasQuotes` function should accept an array of *fixed-length* strings of *any length*, not just `String * 250`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have trouble passing an array of fixed-length strings *of any length*.  One simple solution is to convert them to an array of variable-length strings:

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim rowRec As myRecord
   Dim names(15) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim s As String
   
   rowRec.names(0) = "Brian"
   rowRec.names(15) = "Stafford"

   'move the data to an array of variable-length strings
   For i = 0 To 15
      names(i) = rowRec.names(i)
   Next
   
   s = HasQuotes(names)

   'move the data back to the original array if needed
   For i = 0 To 15
      rowRec.names(i) = names(i)
   Next
End Sub
```